# React error "Uncaught TypeError: type.toUpperCase is not a function" on a hello world app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started dabbling with reactjs, and on following a tutorial and I got the error on the title, just on running a very simple hello world app. Below is the single page code I have:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.js"></script>
        <script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script type="text/jsx">
        // Define a class
        var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
          render: function() {
            return <div>
              Hello World!
            </div>
          }
        });

        // create element with this class
        var element = React.createElement({HelloWorld});

        // Render this class and  place it in the body tag
        React.render(element, document.body);
      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Any hints or resolution are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a mistake in the following line:

```
var element = React.createElement({HelloWorld});
```

It should be:

```
var element = React.createElement(HelloWorld);
```

Notice the lack of the curly braces.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I have created a React element, but I forgot to export it on the end of the file:

```
var React = require('react');

var About = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>The about page</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
export {
    About, About as default
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey the proper way to render the element is

```
React.render(<HelloWorld />, document.body);
```

You don't need to create the element first. So overall your code should look like

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <div > Hello World! < /div>
    }
});

React.render( < HelloWorld / > , document.body);
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Since I am new to react I think I will be checking all this ahead.